# Ads server: how to create?

Tags: android, admob, ads

I need to show Ads on Android app, but these Ads should be stored on my server.
I've heard about AdMob ads network. 
But is there a way to use AdMob (or any other) client lib with my own server?

Comment: Traditionally for both web and mobile, ads are delivered from a third-party server. Why host unless you are building your own ad system?

Comment: Ideally I would like to have client lib (that will download images periodically, cache it, etc.) and server framework (Java would fit best; to display some statistics). Is it even possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can use DoubleClick For Publishers small business edition.

If your familiar with ad mob you can download the double click library and implement it with the ad mob sdk into your app - you can then have the app point to your doubleclick account which would allow you to then serve whatever ads and control what you serve

https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/dfp/fundamentals

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can have your own image caching client and image server but that isn't a ad.

An ad can be a static image, a video ad, or a tap to web ad which would launch a browser or a rich ad which uses a webview to show animated/interactive creative content. In all cases there may be one or more third parties used to verify that the ad actually got delivered.

The purpose of ads is to make money and whole businesses exist to serve brands/advertisers, create ads, show ads, verify that ads were shown and distribute revenue. All of them have publisher (app client) dashboards and most allow some form of house or custom ad.

As AdMob is free to use, I would try it first on a test project to see how it works and then revisit what features are lacking for your use case and check out other vendors.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely. The simplest solution that also gives you flexibility IMO would be to use Admob as a mediator and write a CustomEvent that then loads ads from your server. You would be responsible for writing the CustomEvent (very simple) and your ad server.

See here for how to write a CustomEvent

- https://support.google.com/admob/answer/2576174?hl=en
- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=07wM2ZXHobI